# Stream Continually only reads for 1 minute

Tags: scala, stream, bufferedreader

`Stream.continually` returns empty String if `in.readLine` takes longer than `1 minute`

```
val f = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault.asInstanceOf[SSLSocketFactory]
val s = f.createSocket(ip, port).asInstanceOf[SSLSocket]
 s.startHandshake()
 s.setTcpNoDelay(true)
 val out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream))
 val in  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream))

 val in  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream))    
 Stream.continually(in.readLine()).takeWhile(_ != null).mkString
```

Why does this happen?

Can I change this with some property.

I have gone through the whole Stream Documentation but I think I might be missing something.

I have also tried adding `s.setSoTimeout(300000)`
Also I read the official documentation for `SSLSocketFactory` but could not find any default TimeOut. Also did not find for `SSLSocket`

---

**CONCLUSION** (after debugging this error)

This has nothing to do with Stream. Nor does it has anything to do with `SSLSocketFactory` or `SSLSocket`. It was a timeout problem in the proxy. I got it all wrong.

Comment: What is `s`? A somewhat more complete example would be easier to try out.

Comment: @Michael, I have added the complete code

Comment: I don't think it's a `Stream` issue. If you invoke `Stream.continually(io.StdIn.readLine)...` from the REPL it will wait indefinitely.

Comment: @jwvh do you think it has to do with SSLSocket somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually is unrelated to `Stream`. Try taking `Stream` out of your code:

```
val ip = "74.125.141.147" // google
val port = 443

val f = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault.asInstanceOf[SSLSocketFactory]
val s = f.createSocket(ip, port).asInstanceOf[SSLSocket]
s.startHandshake()
s.setTcpNoDelay(true)

val out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream))
val in  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream))

println {
  in.readLine()
}
```

This eventually prints `null`, as it should (I think when the remote gets bored and hangs up).

What is happening is that `mkString`, given an empty sequence, will produce an empty string.